# Bloco if não está bem localizado, como resolver?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Fiz assim, pelo jeito ele ta dando erro, porque a porta 80 está aberta e ele retorna como fechada

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server = '201.27.188.138'
port = '80'

def MeuScanDaorao(port):
    try:
        s.connect((server, port))
        return True
    except:
        return False

if MeuScanDaorao(port):
    print(MeuScanDaorao('aaa'))
else:
    print('Ta fechada')
```

Esse meu código de baixo funciona, não entendo porque o de cima não. Python é muito legal, preciso aprender só

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server = '201.27.188.138'

def MeuScanDaorao(port):
    try:
        s.connect((server, port))
        return True
    except:
        return False

for x in range(80,81):
    if MeuScanDaorao(x):
        print('Porta', x, 'ta aberta')
    else:
        print('Porta', x,'fechada')
```

Comment: O que seria `MeuScanDaorao('aaa')`?

Comment: Só pra ele mostrar se a porta ta aberta

Comment: Mas você está chamando a função para conectar no servidor pela porta `'aaa'`? Não fez muito sentido isso.

Comment: isso é só o print kkkkk

Comment: Sim, mesmo que seja um print, a função será chamada e continuará sem fazer sentido. Não seria só `print("aaa")`?

Comment: o ' e o " não mudam em nada, os dois são pra comentar, se tivesse escrito sem nada, apenas dentro dos paratenses, ai sim iria printar a função em sí

Answer (score 1):

Como eu comentei, não faz sentido algum você chamar a função para a porta `'aaa'`. Tentei pelos comentários, mas parece ter sido ineficiente.

Seu código está assim:

```
if MeuScanDaorao(port):
    print(MeuScanDaorao('aaa'))
else:
    print('Ta fechada')
```

Que pode ser traduzido para:

1. Tenta conectar na porta 80, `port`;
2. Se conectar com sucesso, exiba o resultado de `MeuScanDaorao('aaa')`;
3. Caso contrário, exiba `'Ta fechada'`;

Se você analisar o item 2, perceberá que o que será exibido é **o retorno da chamada da função `MeuScanDaorao` na porta `'aaa'`**, o que não faz o menor sentido. Provavelmente o resultado de `MeuScanDaorao('aaa')` sempre será `False`, a menos que o servidor possua uma porta `'aaa'`.

Ao invés de fazer essas confusões com chamadas da função, por quê não começa com o simples?

```
if MeuScanDaorao(port):
    print('Porta está aberta')
else:
    print('Porta está fechada')
```

Se mesmo assim exibir que está fechada... bom, é provável que ela esteja fechada mesmo.

Comment: Muito bem observado Anderson e muito obrigado, mas mesmo assim a resposta volta como "fechada", se vc rodar meu script que fiz em range no pycharm com o seu ip externo na porta 80, ele vai mostrar q essa porta está aberta, porque essa porta eh padrão estar aberta

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que a sua intenção é fazer com que o seu `if` fique fora do escopo da função.

Seu bloco `if` deve ser identado no mesmo nível que o `def`, veja só:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server = 'externo'
port = '80'

def MeuScanDaorao(port):
    try:
        s.connect((server, port))
        return True
    except:
        return False

if MeuScanDaorao(port):
    print( MeuScanDaorao('aaa') )
```

Repare que no `Python 3.6`, `print` espera parêntesis.